# How to fit image to parent div with scaling and without stretching

Tags: html, css, image, sass

I have a div that has a certain fixed width and height. I want to fit inside an image (it's dimensions are previously unknown) without stretching it (keep aspect ratio). Object fit would work but for the sake of image being wrapped inside of another wrapper div (to apply shadow), so it cannot be used this time.

To make it clear: I can't use object-fit, nor making it a background image.

**How is this done properly with CSS?**

further images to demonstrate my intentions: (blue rectangle on the right represents the original image in its original size, on the left it is how it should display inside it's dashed parent)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can use 'background-size: contain;' on image

Comment: i need to have that image wrapped inside of another wrapper div to apply box shadow, putting it as a background doesn't solve the issue

Comment: I can't see any shadow in the example image you posted.

Comment: it's not relevant to this issue, i've mentioned it in the post

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. Is the reason you can't use background-image or object-fit because you want a border or shadow around the image itself? If so, I'm looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly this should do it

```
object-fit: contain;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.section{
height:90vh;
width:100%;
border: 2px solid black;

}
.img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1239&q=80');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> you can resize the browser and the aspect ration wont change, I hope this is what you are looking for